# LINQ - join , group by (multiple fields), group by, select new some fields

Tags: linq, group-by

i need select some fields from a table in the query using join, but in the select new statement i dont have acess from the fields of the join table.

```
var query = from p in persistencia.RequisicaoCompraItems
```

join s in persistencia.Suprimentos on p.SuprimentoID equals s.SuprimentoID

**(i need get fields from this join)**

group p by new {p.SuprimentoID, p.RequisicaoCompraItemID, p.RequisicaoCompraID } into x

```
                        from res in x

                        orderby x.Key.SuprimentoID

                        select new {res.SuprimentoID ,

                                    res.RequisicaoCompraItemID,

                                    **but in here i cant acess**  };
```

Cheers**

Answer (score 1):

They're in `res.Key.SuprimentoID` etc